# Vouvoie-t-on ses parents?

Tags: société, vouvoiement

J'aimerais savoir jusqu'à quel point il est normal de vouvoyer ses propres parents ?

J'ai passé cinq ans en France et je n'ai rencontré qu'une seule personne qui utilisait *vous* avec ses parents. Le sujet n'était pas toujours discuté avec tout le monde, donc je ne peux pas être certain, mais, à mon avis, il n'y a que très peu de gens qui vouvoient leurs parents.

En plus, après un peu de temps, je tutoyais mes beaux-parents - c'est-à-dire les parents de ma copine (des deux cotés), et ça s'est fait assez facilement, sans façons.

Mais j'aimerais avoir l'avis de francophones de souche - pour moi, le chiffre doit être dans les un/deux pour cent - même (beaucoup) moins ? À vous de me persuader de changer mon idée/opinion !

Je sais que jadis, le vouvoiement se faisait en famille - ma question concerne plutôt le présent.

Comment: Je n'ai pas de statistiques, mais je pense que c'est extrêmement rare. Dans les livres/films/... on ne voit quasiment jamais ça si ça se passe aujourd'hui, en tout cas.

Comment: Oui, biensûr, jadis ça se faisait. Mais question concerne les pratiques courantes! Merci de votre contribution.

Comment: A noter que le rapport social vis-à-vis de ses propres parents est différent de celui entre gendre/bru et ses beaux-parents. Dans le second cas, le vouvoiement est moins rare (personnellement, j'attendrais que mes beaux-parents me proposent de les tutoyer pour ne pas commettre d'impair).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Étant né à Paris il y a 21 ans et y vivant depuis, tout mon entourage est français. Et depuis ma naissance, je peux t'assurer que jamais ne m'est venu à l'oreille le moindre bruit du fait d'une personne qui  vouvoierait ses parents.

Cela représente au minimum 1 000 personnes dont je suis 100% sûr qu'elles ne vouvoient pas leurs parents.

Ainsi, je pense que l'on est en dessous d'un pourcent pour le vouvoiement de ses parents en France.

Néanmoins, dans la littérature française et dans de nombreuses œuvres datant d'avant le 20e siècle, le vouvoiement était assez courant, tandis que de nos  jours il n'existe pratiquement plus. Il était même d'usage, je me souviens avoir lu plusieurs vieilles œuvres où les protagonistes vouvoyaient leurs parents. Cette pratique tend donc à disparaître.

Pour appuyer mes dires, voici un extrait de [cet article](https://lesvendredisintellos.com/2011/10/14/vouvoiement-enfants-parents-une-tradition-qui-se-perd/) :

> « Même si aujourd’hui, c’est quelque chose qui se fait de plus en plus rare dans les familles, le fait est que jusqu’à la fin du 18ème siècle, il était d’usage que les enfants vouvoient leurs parents. Et ce serait Jean-Jacques Rousseau, grand philosophe du siècle des Lumières, qui serait l’instigateur du tutoiement au sein de la famille.
>
> Les 20 000 familles qui perpétuent cette tradition encore aujourd’hui sont essentiellement de grandes familles bourgeoises, aristocratiques ou catholiques. »

20 000 familles parmi 18 millions de familles en France (chiffres concernant 2011 ; source : INSEE). Cela représente moins de 0,2% de personnes concernées :)

Comment: Bienvenu sur French Stack Exchange ! C'est une bonne première réponse ; j'espère que vous reviendrez en offrir davantage. J'ai corrigé la mise en forme (lien, block quote) et les salutations redondantes.

Comment: Merci de ta réponse - je pense qu'au maximum ça doit représenter 0.1% de la population (1 sur 1000) et même ça c'est une surestimation.

Comment: Très bonne réponse, toutefois cela dépend vraiment des milieux sociaux. Par exemple, dans mon enfance, je fréquentais le conservatoire (un milieu assez "bcbg"), et il y avait là-bas deux ou trois familles où les enfants vouvoyaient leurs parents.

Comment: @Vérace, en effet, le pourcentage de 0.2% de personnes concerne l'année 2011 et a sûrement diminué depuis.

Comment: @Ctouw Je suis d'accord avec ton constat. C'est également légèrement mentionné dans la citation de la réponse, où il est indiqué que les personnes pratiquant toujours cette tradition sont essentiellement issues de la classe bourgeoise ou encore de l'aristocratie.

Answer (score 5):

Au 20<sup>e</sup> ou au 21<sup>e</sup> siècle, vouvoyer ses parents est perçu comme stéréotypiquement aristocratique et arriéré. [Il y a encore des gens qui le font](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/30891), mais ce n'est pas culturellement « normal ».

C'était plus courant autrefois. Il est donc logique que le vouvoiement systématique y compris au sein de la famille proche est assez répandu dans la littérature classique. Mais dans la littérature moderne avec des personnages contemporains, ce serait une indication que le personnage est en décalage avec sa société.

Le vouvoiement a toujours été un marqueur social : plus on est riche ou noble, plus on a tendance à vouvoyer. Ce qui a évolué au fil du temps, c'est la position de ce marqueur. Pendant la Révolution, il y a eu une vague de généralisation du tutoiement : un bon révolutionnaire dit « citoyen, tu … » et non « monsieur, vous ». Le caractère systématique n'a pas survécu à la période la plus intense de la Révolution, mais cela a entraîné une tendance de fond en France de réduction du vouvoiement. Aujourd'hui, il est rare de vouvoyer sa famille, ses amis, un enfant, ou des camarades de classe. Le vouvoiement au travail est plus ou moins fréquent suivant les milieux.

Comment: Je suis curieux : En est-il ainsi pour les époux ? Je pense au stéréotype britannique où une femme dirait à son mari : "Good morning, Mr. Thimblesworth!  How do you do today?" et vice versa ... :)

Comment: @LukeSawczak Je compte l'époux dans la famille, et aussi la belle-famille. Vouvoyer se fait peut-être encore dans certains quartiers de Versailles, mais chez les gens normaux, on commence à se tutoyer au plus tard quand on commence à sortir ensemble.

Comment: Je comprends que c'est son statut de nos jours, mais par le passé était-ce aussi normal que le vouvoiement des parents par les enfants ?

Comment: @LukeSawczak Ah. Je pense que si on vouvoie ses enfants alors on se vouvoie entre époux. Par contre, c'est possible que des époux qui se vouvoient tutoient leurs enfants quand ils sont enfants, je ne suis pas sûr, et je ne sais pas si les enfants tutoieraient aussi. En France, en général, le tutoiement est symétrique (si X tutoie Y alors Y tutoie X), sauf pour les enfants : en général, un adulte tutoie un enfant, mais un enfant vouvoie un adulte hors de sa famille.

Comment: D'accord, merci !

Comment: Merci notamment pour le paragraphe sur la marque sociale. Il me semble que c'est l'élément de réponse principal, étant donné que la question cible explicitement l'usage actuel.

Comment: Merci de la réponse - c'est plus ou moins ce que j'ai pensé.